# how to use depended / non-random observations when trying to inference exponential parameter

Tags: bayesian, exponential-distribution, observational-study

consider this case:

There is a price rate for a certain product that changes throw time,
The price rate is changed every x minutes (unknown, not constant).

This price has **depended / non-random observations**
Meaning there could be 10 observation in a certain time frame and 0 in another
An observation could be {price change, price is the same}

Supposed X is a random variable that track the number of minutes between 2 changes

I understood that X ~ exp(lambda)

I want to inference what is lambda based on the non-uniformed observations
Could it be done?

edit:

bottom line is: i want to know the probability that a certain price rate would change after X time units,
the problem is that i cannot create a controlled experiment and i have to use observation only, these observation are either "price change" or "price is the same"

for example:

| rate | time | status |
| A | 8:00 | not changed |
| A | 8:01 | not changed |
| A | 8:02 | not changed |
| A | 8:12 | not changed |
| A | 9:30 | not changed |
| A | 9:31 | changed |
| A | 15:02 | changed |
| A | 15:03 | not changed |
| A | 15:05 | not changed |

Comment: This isn't very clear. Is it just that you have a [tag:poisson-process] ([Wikipaedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process)), & you want to estimate lambda & get a confidence interval for it? Do you need the answer to be from a Bayesian perspective? Could you post a small, example dataset?

Comment: thanks for replaying @gung
bottom line is: i want to know the probability that a certain price rate would change after X time units,
the problem is that i cannot create a controlled experiment and i have to use observation only, these observation are either "price change" or "price is the same"

example added in description 



for example:  
| rate | time | status |   
| A | 8:00 | not changed |  
| A | 8:01 | not changed | 
| A | 9:30 | not changed |
| A | 9:31 | changed |